# Git like change and version management of complete machine

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, backup

We have a Centos machine on which Jenkins is hosted.

This Jenkins have lots of jobs and configurations of interconnected jobs.

The problem  is that if anytime we want to do a change in multiple jobs there is a risk of misconfiguration.

So there should be a revert process so that we can revert back to older working version of Jenkins.

Just like git does, if code is buggy I have the option to revert back to the healthy code.

Is there any standard solution available for these type of problems?

Comment: Have you seen https://www.coveros.com/version-control-your-jenkins-server-configuration-with-git/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the files on JENKINS_HOME;

A far better approach would be using [thinBackup](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/thinBackup)

Using **thinBackup** you can restore and make a backup.